# Can't debug directly on ADT-1 Developer Kit

Tags: android, adt, android-5.0-lollipop, android-tv

I"m working on an application for `Android TV` by `ADT-1 Developer Kit`.
I can install the application from `Eclipse`. But I can't debug step by step directly.
I run Debug but It doesn't go to any breakpoint. Even though I enabled `USB Debugging`.
A more weird thing is when I install application on ADT-1 Developer Kit, It doesn't start application automatically, although the application logo appears on TV UI.
This is the following Manifiest file:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="21"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
<uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="false" />

.....
<activity android:name="vng.zing.tv.activity.LoginActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
   </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

And It shows the log like below

```
Android Launch!
adb is running normally.
No Launcher activity found!
The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
Performing sync
Automatic Target Mode: Several compatible targets. Please select a target device.
Uploading Example.apk onto device 'ZW2Z142308EE'
Installing Example.apk...
Success!
\Example\bin\Example.apk installed on device
```

It doesn't find the `Activity` to start.

What should I do to solve the problem? Thanks

Comment: Have you tried restarting the ADB? It happens to me as well while using Android Studio. I usually need to restart the IDE and/or to restart ADB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I don't know the reasons behind this, **restarting the ADB** and/or **restarting the IDE** usually does the trick.

If you're `adb connect`-ing to ADT-1, then do

```
adb disconnect adt_addr:4321
adb connect adt_addr:4321
```

where `adt_addr` is obviously the IP address of your ADT-1.

If none of the above is working, then it's probably something wrong with the workspace. Try the following:

1. Uninstall the application
2. Clean the workspace and rebuild the project
3. Install the application again

---

I also discovered a **bug on ADB + Studio** with Android TV: if you clear the logs via the `Trash` button, then the `adb logcat` breaks and you won't see any log. Performing a disconnect-reconnect brings back things to normal.

Comment: It works if I use android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER". If I change to android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER", the issue  happens again. I already restarted the ADB and IDE. But It doesn't work.

Comment: I'm using the developer cable

Comment: Since you're on Eclipse, try this: uninstall the app, clean the project and reinstall again. Also, consider switching to Android Studio, since Eclipse is no longer supported the Android Developer Toolkit.